# Blazor Select Element I Can Not Set The ChangeEvent

Tags: html, blazor-webassembly

I can not see how to set the change event on select element when that element is bound to a field.
When I select a name in the name chooser list the 2nd list reflects the change.

```
<div>
    <p>Name Chooser</p>
    <select @onchange="OnChange">
        @foreach (var name in Names)
        {
            <option>@name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>


<select @bind="@chosenName"> 
    @foreach (var name in Names)
    {
        <option>@name</option>
    }
</select>



@code{
    string chosenName = "Peter";
    List<string> Names = new List<string>() { "Paul", "Peter", "Jane", "Jackie" };

    void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        chosenName = e.Value.ToString();
    }
    void OnChange2(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

My question is how to detect the change event on list 2 when I select it with the mouse. This code throws a compiler error.

```
<select @bind="@chosenName" @onchange="OnChange2">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to bind anything, because the `onchange` event sends out all the information you will need for a dropdown.  In many cases, you won't even need an event handler.  You can just set a variable with a lambda method.

Maybe something like:

```
<div>
    <p>Name Chooser</p>
    <select @onchange="args => chosenName = args.Value.ToString()">
        @foreach (var name in Names)
        {
            <option selected>@name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<select @onchange="OnChange2">
    @foreach (var name in Names)
    {
        if (name == chosenName)
        {
            <option selected>@name</option>
        }
        else
        {
            <option>@name</option>
        }
    }
</select>

@code{
    string chosenName = "Peter";
    List<string> Names = new List<string>() { "Paul", "Peter", "Jane", "Jackie" };

    void OnChange2(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the selected attribute on the option tag that does the trick?

Comment: Yeah that's right.  Overall, I recommend not thinking too much of things as objects like you might do in Web Forms, but more like interactive html.  So you can go check out HTML5 specs and so on, and pretty much just form things however you like.  There are several other useful attributes that you can use as well https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach using getters and setters.  It lets Blazor handle the control events.

```
@page "/select2"
<div>
    <p>Name Chooser</p>
    <select @bind="name">
        @foreach (var name in Names)
        {
            <option>@name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>


<select @bind="@chosenName">
    @foreach (var name in Names)
    {
        <option>@name</option>
    }
</select>



@code{

    string name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_name))
            {
                _name = value;
                // do something or trigger an event;
                _chosenname = value;
            }
        }
    }

    string chosenName
    {
        get => _chosenname;
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_chosenname))
            {
                _chosenname = value;
                // do something or trigger an event;
            }
        }
    }

    string _name = null;
    string _chosenname = "Peter";
    List<string> Names = new List<string>() { "Paul", "Peter", "Jane", "Jackie" };
}
```